# Python: lists in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I've been trying to get mediana from this list which means the list that has shortest [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).

I have made a function euclid that returns the distance between 2 vectors regardless of their size, but I have a problem with 2 for loops.

This program should return [1,2,3]

```
xs=[[1, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1], [1, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
naj = 0
vsota=0
ys=[]
for i,j in enumerate(xs):
    for x,y in enumerate(xs):
        if j!=y:
            vsota=euclid(j,y)

            print(vsota,"            ",j,y)
```

but it currently returns:

```
2.23606797749979                [1, 1, 1] [3, 2, 1]
2.23606797749979                [1, 1, 1] [1, 0, 3]
2.23606797749979                [1, 1, 1] [1, 2, 3]
5.196152422706632               [1, 1, 1] [4, 4, 4]
2.23606797749979                [3, 2, 1] [1, 1, 1]
3.4641016151377544              [3, 2, 1] [1, 0, 3]
2.8284271247461903              [3, 2, 1] [1, 2, 3]
3.7416573867739413              [3, 2, 1] [4, 4, 4]
2.23606797749979                [1, 0, 3] [1, 1, 1]
3.4641016151377544              [1, 0, 3] [3, 2, 1]
2.0                             [1, 0, 3] [1, 2, 3]
5.0990195135927845              [1, 0, 3] [4, 4, 4]
2.23606797749979                [1, 2, 3] [1, 1, 1]
2.8284271247461903              [1, 2, 3] [3, 2, 1]
2.0                             [1, 2, 3] [1, 0, 3]
3.7416573867739413              [1, 2, 3] [4, 4, 4]
5.196152422706632               [4, 4, 4] [1, 1, 1]
3.7416573867739413              [4, 4, 4] [3, 2, 1]
5.0990195135927845              [4, 4, 4] [1, 0, 3]
3.7416573867739413              [4, 4, 4] [1, 2, 3]
```

How do I sum up all the numbers that start with [1,1,1], [3,2,1]...etc and then compare the distances with each and then return the index with the lower sum?

Comment: Did you solve this? Was any of the answer useuful?

Answer (score 0):

Already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119644/identifying-points-with-the-smallest-euclidean-distance) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370975/python-numpy-euclidean-distance-calculation-between-matrices-of-row-vectors) or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709720/euclidian-distance-python-implementation)?
There are many solutions on stackoverflow or other platforms, and I'm sure you checked them out. So what'ts wrong with them?

Comment: lol i am sorry i tottaly forogot to check with euclidean distance as search parameter. as you can see i didnt even use it in a question

Comment: now i checked them and thats not what i am asking for. i know how to get distance my function euclid does it (tho i didnt publish the code for it)
the problem is how do i get the list inside list that has the shortest euclidean distance, what condition should i use. i should be compering all the distances for each list and then chose list wit the shortest distances comparing to others. Also i dont have numpy module and as far as i know i should not need it

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use two variables to keep track of the lowest?

```
lowest_vsota = 0
lowest_coord = []
```

Then in the if block ...

```
if vsota < lowest_vsota:
    lowest_vsota = vsota
    lowest_coord = j
```